[gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet-modal]When enableContentPanningGesture false is , scrolling using BottomSheetScrollView is not possible on iOS
If I am using scrollview from react then I am able to scroll, but  keyboard is not handled properly. It would be great to be able to use BottomSheetScrollView even when enableContentPanningGesture is set to false
  <BottomSheetModal
    ref={bottomSheetModaRef}
    backdropComponent={props => (
      <BottomSheetCustomBack {...props} onPressFunc={closeModal} />
    )}
    keyboardBehavior="interactive"
    android_keyboardInputMode="adjustResize"
    enablePanDownToClose={true}
    enableContentPanningGesture={false}
    handleComponent={()=>(<BottomSheetHandleComponent closeModal={closeModal} title = {title}/>)}
    onDismiss={onDismissFunc}
    enableDynamicSizing={true}
    topInset={50}
    {...props}
    >
    <BottomSheetScrollView> 
      <View> 
        
      </View>
    </BottomSheetScrollView>
  </BottomSheetModal>


which packages you are using for the bottom sheet?

@Talha i am using react-native--bottom-sheet from gorhom

Does this answer your question? Scroll content inside @gorhom/bottom-sheet - React Native
